# Center a box with right aligned text

Tags: imagemagick

Below I have an example where there's a bg image (red 300x300) and I'd like to have a foreground image (blue 100x100), with text inside it.

| Want | Have |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

```sh
convert -size 300x300 xc:red ( -fill blue -draw rectangle 0,100 100,0  -fill white -pointsize 20 -gravity NorthWest -draw text 0,0 "hello
world" ) -gravity Center
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do that in ImageMagick. Unix Syntax

```
convert -size 300x300 xc:red \( -size 100x100 -background blue -pointsize 18 -fill white label:"Hello\nWorld" \) -gravity center -compose over -composite result.png
```

[image]

For Windows syntax, remove the \ before ( and before )

Comment: You're a lifesaver, I would have been twiddling my thumbs all day. ❤️

Comment: Your command has -gravity center at the end and no output image. Gravity is a setting and does nothing without some operator such as -composite to process it. ImageMagick syntax is:  `read input, settings, operators to act on settings, write output`